# Touchscreen not working on suspend. No existing solutions are working

Tags: suspend, laptop, touchscreen, 16.04

When I close the lid to suspend my laptop the touchscreen stops working after waking the laptop.

I found a workaround by sleeping the laptop before closing the lid. For some reason if the laptop is slept with the lid opened and then closed while asleep, the touchscreen works fine when waking from sleep.

Why is it that my touchscreen stops working if I close the lid to sleep it? Is there any commands I can run to re-enable the touchscreen after it stops working?

Comment: It's possible that the touch feature is disabled when the laptop is closed, right before it goes to sleep, and isn't re-enabled when you wake the computer. However, 16.04 is in beta, and any issues you encounter with it should be reported as bugs on Launchpad.

Comment: Well I'm assuming it happens on older versions as well. I disable lid close actions and the touchscreen is never disabled. If I run the suspend command and close the lid immediately it breaks.

I don't know how I would report this issue on launchpad, I really just want to know what logs I can read or what devices I can probe to find out what is happening.